# how to remove get request in kaminari pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

Now I have pagination slug like this:

`/catalog?page=5` but `/catalog/page5` is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more background information as to what you have tried and what is failing. Reading this might help http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of how you can achieve that

```
concern :paginatable do
  get '(page/:page)', action: :index, on: :collection, as: ''
end

resources :my_resources, concerns: :paginatable
```

You can refer to [documentation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching) for further information